# MySQL Query Problem

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to php and mysql and am having an issue with a query.

```
SELECT candidate_id.master_id, candidate_contact_details.first_name,
candidate_contact_details.last_name,
candidate_contact_details.home_phone FROM candidate_id,
candidate_contact_details, qualifications WHERE qualifications.active = 'yes';
```

The database only has 2 records across 5 tables but this is returning 12 results in both php and directly on the mysql console. I know I am doing something wrong but cannot figure it out.

Comment: you are missing some condition to relate the 3 tables in this *raw* join

Comment: Can you improve on this question's title? We know it's "MySQL" because you tagged it as such, and if you didn't have a "Problem" then you wouldn't be here. Pick a title that distinguishes this question from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make the query consistent.
the query you have is the Cartesian product of all your tables which in most of the case doesn't make much sense

here is something better (assuming that `master_id` is the reference to a candidate instance):

```
SELECT candidate_id.master_id, candidate_contact_details.first_name,
candidate_contact_details.last_name,
candidate_contact_details.home_phone
FROM candidate_id, candidate_contact_details, qualifications
WHERE qualifications.active = 'yes' AND candidate_id.master_id = candidate_contact_details.master_id AND qualifications.master_id = candidate_id.master_id;
```

even better would be use `JOIN` and use alias for table name to make code more readable:

```
SELECT c.master_id, cc.first_name,cc.last_name,cc.home_phone
FROM candidate_id c
   JOIN candidate_contact_details cc
     ON c.master_id = cc.master_id
   JOIN qualifications q
     ON c.master_id = q.master_id
WHERE q.active = 'yes';
```

Comment: actually, your first query *is* a join (raw)..:)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the speedy and very helpful responses. I get the idea now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT candidate_id.master_id, candidate_contact_details.first_name, candidate_contact_details.last_name, candidate_contact_details.home_phone FROM candidate_id, candidate_contact_details, qualifications WHERE qualifications.active = 'yes' and candidate_id.master_id = candidate_contact_details.master_id and candidate_id.master_id = qualification.master_id;

Make sure that master_id column exists across all the tables and its name is correct.

As daniele said, the query needs to be inner join not cartesian product in the case that you have described.
Have you declared foreign keys on these tables?

Comment: oops. looks like daniele also added modified SQL query !

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on how to join SQL tables. Unless the query specifies how rows in one table relate to rows in another table, the database will join each row to *every other row* in the other table.